# Why does the order of closing two IO pipes in two forks matter?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, io, subprocess, fork

Running the following code in Ruby makes `Process.wait p1` to hang indefinitely. This is seemingly because `r1.eof?` in the first subprocess does not get unblocked by `w1.close` in the parent process.

```rb
r1, w1 = IO.pipe
p1 = fork { w1.close; r1.eof? }
r1.close

r2, w2 = IO.pipe
p2 = fork { w2.close; r2.eof? }
r2.close

sleep 1

w1.close
puts "Wait for p1"; Process.wait p1

w2.close
puts "Wait for p2"; Process.wait p2
```

My confusion is around why this does not work, and why the following (turning around the closing of writers and wait for process 1 and process 2), executes and exits the program successfully:

```rb
r1, w1 = IO.pipe
p1 = fork { w1.close; r1.eof? }
r1.close

r2, w2 = IO.pipe
p2 = fork { w2.close; r2.eof? }
r2.close

sleep 1

w2.close
puts "Wait for p2"; Process.wait p2

w1.close
puts "Wait for p1"; Process.wait p1
```

**However**, as soon as I put the second snippet's logic in a class, it does *not* work anymore:

```rb
class Client
  def initialize
    @r, @w = IO.pipe
  end

  def start
    @pid = fork { @w.close; @r.eof? }
    @r.close
  end

  def stop
    @w.close
    puts "Wait for #@pid"; Process.wait(@pid)
  end
end

clients = 2.times.map { Client.new }
clients.each(&:start)
sleep 1
clients.reverse.each(&:stop)
```

What is going on here?

Digging a bit deeper, and using the knowledge that all file descriptors in memory that the parent process has created thus far, will be available in the forked process, I found out that I can make it work by storing all opened IO readers and writers in a class variable `@@opened_io`, and close all irrelevant readers and writers in the fork with `@@opened_io.reject { |io| io.closed? || io == @r }.each(&:close)`, like so:

```rb
class Client
  @@opened_io = []

  def initialize
    @r, @w = IO.pipe
    @@opened_io.concat([@r, @w])
  end

  def start
    @pid = fork do 
      @@opened_io.reject { |io| io.closed? || io == @r }.each(&:close) 
      @r.eof?
    end

    @r.close
  end

  def stop
    @w.close
    puts "Wait for #@pid"; Process.wait(@pid)
  end
end

clients = 2.times.map { Client.new }
clients.each(&:start)
sleep 1
clients.each(&:stop)
```

Why is this so important?